# Accessing values from a loop in VB.Net from another function using button click event handler

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to create a new POS system using VB.Net but am a beginner with it. I have a problem. Basically I use an online SQL database using which different categories of items for the POS can be added by the admin. Since all the items have been stored in an SQL table I have managed to retrieve that information based on categories and display them in the form of buttons on my POS system.

Now the problem is that the loop holds all the information related to the different buttons created and when I try to access the value of the current category being clicked on from another button it doesn't seem to give me the current value but instead gives me the last value which was updated in the loop. I'm leaving an example of the code below:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form13
    Dim arr(100) As String
    Public verifier(1) As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Public value As String

    Public Sub Form13_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim point As Integer
        Dim point1 As Integer
        point = 20
        point1 = 100
        counter = 0
        Label2.Text = Form12.selected_value
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection
        connection.ConnectionString = ("host=localhost;user=root;password=;database=pos;")
        connection.Open()
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("select * from categories", connection)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        While reader.Read()
            Dim button As New Button
            value = reader.GetString("category_name")

            button.Name = value
            button.Text = value
            button.Height = 50
            button.Width = 190
            button.Font = New Font("arial", 11)
            button.Location = New Point(point, point1)
            Me.Controls.Add(button)
            point1 = point1 + 50
            counter = counter + 1
            verifier(0) = counter
            arr(counter) = value

            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf button_Click
            button_Click()
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub button_Click()
        MsgBox(arr(counter))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Shown above is the code where the category name is gathered from the MySQL table and later a single button is being reused until all the buttons have been created for all existing category names in the MySQL table. Now the outcome I would like is to have the name of the category when the relevant button is being clicked in the form of a MsgBox in the button handler. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The SQL table is being hosted using XAMPP and a screenshot of the category table used in the code above is shown below: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPNtV.png)

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. It will point out errors that can result in runtime errors.

Comment: @Mary Im not having any runtime errors though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you have a the `String value` which is a referenced object. 
Your loop adds the same reference to the string with every iteration of your loop.
The reference tells your programm where to look for the value in you RAM. The value for the same object gets updated every iteration so every entry has the same data.

You can fix this by declaring the `Public value as String` within the loop. That way every time you create a new reference.

Remove this line:

```
Public value As String
```

Change this line:

```
value = reader.GetString("category_name")
```

to:

```
Dim value as String = reader.GetString("category_name")
```

Comment: I do understand the logic that you have applied in the code but the problem is that I am not able to declare a public variable within the loop reason being why I have declared it above in the pubic class and the other problem is that me declaring the variable locally using DIM will not allow me to access its value in the button_click function which is where I want to obtain the value in the form of a messagebox. I really appreciate your advice. But please help me further with the problem. Many thanks

Comment: You can declare the value using DIM within the loop. Because your Array has a class scope you are still able to access the value in the ClickEvent. You pass the reference to the value to the array and therefore the value changes it's scope to the scope of the Array.
Just try it

Comment: sorry to bother you but I am kind of new to this language so I have done the change where I have locally created value as string using DIM every time the loop runs and have used the array in the end to call the value being clicked on but then it only gives me the value of the last category name which had been run in the loop. Please help

Comment: As far as i understand, thats what you have programmed. You run a loop n times and count a counter for each iteration. When you click the button (or the function is handled from your loop), you prompt out the value arr(counter) which is infact the last one.
What do you expect to see?

Comment: That is the problem I am facing Im not sure how to obtain the value of the button being selected for example if a button having the value of "soft drinks" has been clicked I would like the msgbox to say "soft drinks" if that makes sense.

Comment: If thats what you want your code does not make sense.

In that case i recommend changing the handler to a lambda.
        `AddHandler button.Click, Sub()
                                      MsgBox(arr(counter))
                                  End Sub`

Comment: Your an absolute legend thank you so much for the help. I was trying to figure out how to put the function of btn_click in the same loop this whole time and you introduced me to the lambda. Seriously I cant thank you enough.

Comment: If you think you may want to later remove the handler, make sure you build with `Option Strict On` to catch differences in the signature of the handler you supply from the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I used SQL Server because that is where I had a sample database. Just use the sender's Name or Text to find what category button was clicked.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form3

    Public Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim value As String
        Dim point As Integer
        Dim point1 As Integer
        point = 20
        point1 = 100
        Label2.Text = Form12.selected_value
        Using connection As New SqlConnection
            connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.BuildersConnectio
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from Builders", connection)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            connection.Open()
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read()
                Dim button As New Button
                value = reader.GetString(1)
                button.Name = value
                button.Text = value
                button.Height = 50
                button.Width = 190
                button.Font = New Font("arial", 11)
                button.Location = New Point(point, point1)
                Me.Controls.Add(button)
                point1 = point1 + 50
                AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf button_Click
            End While
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim ProductCategory = btn.Name
        MessageBox.Show(ProductCategory)
    End Sub
End Class
```